# How to zoom to current user location?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkuserlocation

I want to show current user location in center and also want to show `15km` distance on all sides from current location. How to achieve that?

Comment: Actually i am developing tourist guide kind of app. In app i need to show custom annotations in app, i have done that part. There is option to show current user location with zoom in. I don't know how to do that. I am very new to map programming. Please can you help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
- (void)zoomToUserLocationAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate2D = _locationManager.location;
    CLLocationDistance distance = 30000;

    [self setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationCoordinate2D, distance, distance)
           animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: As I know, MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance method accept east-to-west distance in meters, so i need to set 30000 meters for distance. I want to show 15km in all directions from current location with zoom also

Comment: One more thing it will automatically zoom to that region or do i need to set other parameters?

Comment: It will zomm to this region automatically. You don't need to set other parameters. However you need to declare and initialize the `_locationManager` but I guess you have already done this.

Comment: Thanks. Finally i have done that. Can you please tell me when set showUserLocation of mapview to yes, automatically show current location with update?

Comment: No problem :) You can set it in `viewDidLoad` for example.

Comment: I have set mapview.showUserLocation = YES, But i want to know that whether it show the location automatically when it updates?

Comment: Yes, the annotation for current user location will update automatically when the location changes. You can test it in simulator by setting a custom location.